# Какое регулярное выражение нужно чтобы выбрать все символы после знака двоеточия во всех строках

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Помогите составить RegExp выражение.
Нужно выбрать все символы после знака двоеточия во всех строках.

Title: Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid
Release Year: 1969
Format: VHS
Stars: Paul Newman, Robert Redford, Katherine Ross

Comment: Title: Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid \n                  
Release Year: 1969 \n
Format: VHS \n
Stars: Paul Newman, Robert Redford, Katherine Ross \n

Comment: текст на разных строках

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) очень удобно отлаживать все регулярные выражения, а так же там есть подробное описание всех шаблонов.

Вам подойдет вот такое выражение `:\s+([^\n]+)`